# How can I use two AWS access keys on the same computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to use two different AWS accounts on my computer. One is for my work and the other one is for my personal project.

I made a new Elastic Beanstalk application with eb-cli commands to create a new application for my personal project. When I initially ran `eb init`, it didn't ask me to input AWS access id. Because of that, it made a new application in my work AWS account because its AWS access key is already stored on my computer.

How can I use two AWS accounts separately so that I can manage my personal and work projects separately on the same computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple **profiles** in `~/.aws/credentials` that's then used by most AWS command line tools, including `eb` and `aws`...

```
[invalid]
# Prevent 'aws' from running with default creds
region = us-nonsense-1
aws_access_key_id = AKAINVALID1234567890
aws_secret_access_key = InvalidInvalidInvalidInvalidInvalidAccnt

[work]
region = ap-southeast-2
aws_access_key_id = AKIAWORKACCOUNTXYZ12
aws_secret_access_key = Abcdefg....

[personal]
region = ap-southeast-2
aws_access_key_id = AKIAPERSONALACCESS99
aws_secret_access_key = Zxcvbnm....
```

Then specify the account / profile you want with shell variable `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=work` or with `aws --profile work ...`.

I guess `eb` should support some way to specify the profile on the command line too. If not you can always use the shell environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=...`.

Other options are described in **[EB CLI Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-credentials)** page.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Since this might affect my company AWS account, I was very afraid of trying on my own. That's exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate that. :)

Comment: By the way, is the file name `credentials` required? or can it be something else? I just checked my `.aws` folder and there is a file named `config` which has my company AWS access key. So, I was wondering if I can just put the my personal AWS access key if the file name doesn't matter.

Comment: @Jay it can be in `config` but then the syntax is a little different: `[profile work]` instead of just `[work]` when in `credentials` file.

Comment: I like the idea of an invalid default :)